# Wikimedia Template Font

Tags: mediawiki-api, wikimedia

Does any one know how to get the {{font}} template working in wikimedia?  I have just about given up as I cannot find any solid documentation on how to install it.  Whenever I wrap text in the {{font}} template it render the text as Template:font ..

This is just ridiculous.  I searched on install template, download template, etc.. And just nothing worthwhile comes up.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same template as the english wikipedia, than you can have a look at their template page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Font

and download it, by switching to the "View source" tap in the top right:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Font&action=edit

Just copy that code into your own wiki into a page called "Template:Font" and see what happens.

Comment: Wikipedia now responds with
"You do not have permission to edit this page, for the following reason: <blah blah>"

Comment: @fairflow Could you please send my the URL of the page, that shows the permission error message? Both links still work fine for me (not logged in).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Font&action=edit
exactly as 2nd link above; but the source does still show up and it's probably because I don't understand the source that I thought it wasn't working.  Apologies!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just scroll down - there will be a readonly textbox.